# Setting activity theme WindowBackground causing ActionBar to be null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

I made a small change to set the WindowBackground for my main activity.  Doing so has caused the ActionBar to become null.

First I added a new style:

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
```

Then I changed the manifest for the main activity to reference the style:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

That's it.  The action bar is null.  For example, it's null in this code:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  View contentView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.main_activity, null);
  setContentView (contentView);

  ActionBar b = getActionBar();
  ...
}
```

Am I missing something?  What do I need to do so that the ActionBar is created?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the theme of your application ?

Comment: the same: Theme.Light

Comment: Make sure the setContentView(view) has been already called for your Activity, otherwise getActionBar() will return null.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Theme.Light` as parent theme. This theme is used as default theme in Android from v1 to v10. `Actionbar` was introduced in v11, so when using the old theme, `ActionBar` will be null. If you want to use `ActionBar`, use `Theme.Holo.Light` or `Theme.Material.Light` as parent.